# Add a period to the middle string PHP

Tags: php

It will actually be a decimal but that is not the main point. I will have a set of numbers like:

```
8976
8765
3454
3453
10198
```

What I am wanting to do is add a decimal 2 places from the right. So the first would be 89.76 and so forth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can't you just multiply each by 0.01?

Comment: And change your nice, exact [integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) into approximated [floating point numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)?  Why?

Comment: I guess I could. After spending all day working with this stuff I never thought to use math instead of a programming way around it.

Comment: Rolled back edit -- `8796 * 0.001 = 8.796`.  It is supposed to be `* 0.01` or divide by 100

Comment: @Michael I'm sorry. I really am getting things wrong. I will not edit anything anymore today :)

Comment: @Pekaa, I think 1000 is too much :)

Comment: @Pekka no problem. funny thing was, I got confused enough I actually went back and checked the math myself!

Comment: Thanks guys, I feel this was a waste of time now. I am ready to go home

Answer (score 7):

```
$formatted = number_format($unformatted_number / 100, 2, '.', '');
```

2 - decimal places
'.' - decimal separator
'' - thousands separator

docs for the function are [here](http://php.net/number_format).

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$number = 8976;
$number = (float)$number/100;
```

results:

```
89.76
```

You may have to do some checking to see how many digits the number is, i.e `89768` would be devided by `1000` and so on.

Comment: Same as above, it will always add the period two chars from the left, not the right as he asked.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are available,

```
//the string you need to split
$string = "123456";

// read from right 2 character
$rightNums = substr($string, -2, 2);

// maximum 100 character to the left defined now
$otherNums = substr($string, -4, 100);

// pront them just with . between

echo $otherNums.".".$rightNums; ?>
```

hope it help much.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
 $tmpString = substr("8976", 0, -2);
 $finalString = str_replace($tmpString, "." . $tmpString, "8976");

 echo $finalString;
```